# Adding perpendicular lines to points along a polyline

Tags: qgis, python

I'm looking for a method to add perpendicular lines at points along a polyline. Essentially I'm searching for a solution in QGIS or Python (I'm aware of an ArcGIS solution available here: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3f05ef15203e4a3ca88fc1d92347512b.

[image]

A similar question ([How to add a perpendicular line to the start & end nodes of every polyline?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149723/how-to-add-a-perpendicular-line-to-the-start-end-nodes-of-every-polyline)) addresses what I'm looking to achieve, but again, I need a QGIS/Python solution.

Does anybody have any advice? Currently I'm using the QChainage plugin to generate equally spaced points across lines (see below), but can't find a method to generate perpendicular lines from the points.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget  to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I happen to have a similar problem...

Comment: @user32882 No I did not, please let me know if you find a solution

Comment: I'm looking into v.transects https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/addons/v.transects.html. Also take a look at my recent post in StackExchange https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290595/where-is-the-v-transects-algorithm-in-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290568/dividing-a-buffer-into-segments-based-on-path-and-distance. Really it is quite surprising that v.transects cannot be found anywhere!